# Album artists and Albumtitle warning when upload to AppStore in XCode5

Tags: app-store, ios7, xcode5

I am suprised when i upload my music app to `AppStore` and got this following warning messages.

I used following codes that change the indexBar Background color in my `UITableView`.

```
[[self tableViewMain] setSectionIndexColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [[self tableViewMain] setSectionIndexBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

[image]

What is that and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have used a private API, That not public one. Apple will generally reject your app if you use this because they are not permitted and if Apple changes the internal system (included this undocumented code) it can crash your app. And people would leave negative reviews.

Please check the Update of you used third-Party Private API Download Latest SDK of it and use this into you existing Project. Hope your Issue solve.

Comment: This is my update app for iOS7. my previous version is approved. :(

Comment: Try to Download Letest third-Party Private API SDK and use this

Comment: which third-party API are you using into you project

Comment: i used this code to retrieved album from library . 
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery albumsQuery];
    query.groupingType = MPMediaGroupingAlbum;
    self.arrayOfAlbums = [[query collections] mutableCopy];